# Select objects through uv island

Tags: modeling, uv

I am an Autodesk 3d Max user and am now working with Blender 2.9 for quite some time... I have a bit of a problem. Can I select objects through UV islands ?

Actually, there is a character and there are thousands of hair cards... All the hair cards have the same geometry. I want to tweak the position of  some cards according to the UV tile.... But it is very difficult to select cards manually.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. Click on the double diagonal arrows on the top left of the UV editor and then you can select using UV editor.

[image]